# Deformation of eigenspaces of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have an invertible $n \times n$(complex valued)matrix $A$ , it acts on complex vector space $V$ with dimension $n$. And $V=V_1 \oplus... \oplus V_i$ , $ V_i$'s are eigenspaces of $A$. Consider a continuous family of invertible matrix $A(t)$ with $A(0)=A$. How will the eigenspaces change with small $t$?
I believe that $V$ still can be decomposed as
$$ V=V_{1t} \oplus... \oplus V_{it} \\
$$
and the canonical projection
$$
  \pi_i: V_{i t} \rightarrow V_i \text {, }
$$
is an isomorphism. Is it true, if so , how to prove?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. What can happen is that an eigenvalue can split into two or more.
Consider e.g. $A(t) = I + t B$, where for $t = 0$ you just have the one eigenspace $V$ but for $t \ne 0$ the eigenspaces are those of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a continuity of the Spectrum of a matrix (ordered with multiplicity) However you must be careful about how you define your $V_i (t)$ since they are unique up to permutation... (maybe you have forgotten to pus $A$ diagonalizable also...)

Since the set of diagonalizable matrices is open, there is no pb with a local property.

There is one case where your theorem does not work, when one eigenvalue has a multiplicity $>1$, for example
$A = I_2$, you can define $A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} t & 0\\ 0 & 2t \end{pmatrix}$, then for $t \neq 0$ you have $V_1(t) = \mathbb{C}e_1$ and $V_2(t) = \mathbb{C}e_2$, but $V = V_0$ so the decomposition is not even the same!

If you fix the multiplicities of your eigenvalues (i.e. they are constant in $t$) it could work, but then you would have $\lambda_i (t)$ of multiplicity $m_i$ and $\lambda_i$ a continuous map (direct consequence of the continuity of the spectrum. An easy case is when $A$ has $n$ different Eigenvalues, since the set of such matrices is open it would work. You would then set $V_i(t) = E_{\lambda_i (t)}$ of dimension $m_i$

The thing is that this case is not very interesting, $A(t)$ can be expressed as
$$P(t) \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1(t) I_{m_1} \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_r(t) I_{r_1}  \end{pmatrix}P(t)^{-1}$$
with $P(t)$ a continuous function to $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ so you directly have $V_i (t) = P(t) (\text{Span}(e_{m_1 + \dots + m_{i-1} + 1}, \dots , e_{m_1 + \dots + m_i}))$ where $e_i$ is the i-th vector of the canonical basis.

In this case, the final answer is that $V_i (t)$ changes continuously in the projective variety $\text{Gr}_{m_i,n}$ which is the grassmanian: variety of $m_i$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$.